# Realizar una acción cuando se de click a un elemento con class="flat" de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un ejemplo sencillo para mostrar o no un `<div id="oculto"></div>` al dar click en un `input checkbox` usando `javascript`. Pero tengo la peculiaridad que cuando realizo el evento `click` no se ejecuta la acción de mostrar lo que esta oculto. Este input de `type="checkbox"` tiene un `class="flat"` que permite darle mejor apariencia al `checkbox`; y me he dado cuenta que cuando quito este `class="flat"` de `Bootstrap` la función que se ejecuta con el evento `$('#es_titulo').click(function (){});` funciona perfectamente.

Quizás sea algún detalle del cual no me estoy percatando y resulte muy sencilla la solución, pero dejo el código buscando alguna sugerencia.

El checbox:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="flat" id="es_titulo" > Proceso de T&iacute;tulo
            </label>
        </div>

<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 2%; display: none;" id="caja_bolsa">
  
   
</div>
```

La función que utilizo para mostrar:

```
    $('#es_titulo').click(function (){

        if ($('#es_titulo').prop('checked')) {

            $('#caja_bolsa').show();
            
        } else {
          
            $('#caja_bolsa').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta casilla de verificación es proporcionada por el complemento iCheck que, por alguna razón, se superpone a mi función. Después de descubrir esto, cambié mi función para usar las funciones del complemento iCheck. Así es como fue:

```
$('#es_titulo').on('ifChecked',function() {
        
        $('#caja_bolsa').show();
        
    });
```

Pero el problema que se me presenta ahora es que cuando desmarco el `checkbox` no me se me ejecuta `$('#caja_bolsa').hide();` correctamente. Segui investigando y encontre la propiedad ifChanged y me funciono perfecto.

```
$('#es_titulo').on('ifChanged', function(event) {

        if(event.target.checked){
            $('#caja_bolsa').show();
        } else {
            $('#titulo').val('');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de la version de iCheck que estes usando poder usar esto

```
$('#es_titulo').on('ifChanged',function() {
    if ($('#es_titulo').prop('checked')) {
        $('#caja_bolsa').show();
    } else {
        $('#caja_bolsa').hide();
    }
});
```

Te paso los eventos que tiene iCheck en la documentacion de GitHub

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Casualmente encontré investigando el uso del ifChanged y mi problema desaparecio

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#caja_bolsa').show();
```

y

```
$('#caja_bolsa').hide();
```

lo que hacen es poner y quitar el

```
display: none;
```

todo bien asta aquí

#### el problema se arregla si

ponemos **bg-primary** o cualquiera de sus variantes al elemento **id="caja_bolsa"**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 bg-primary" style="padding-top: 2%; display: none;" id="caja_bolsa">
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]